# Validation Rule Error is not getting Displayed

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a custom object and replicated the same using Visual force, and also have written a validation rule saying "Source should not be equal to destination". But when i am clicking on save its not throwing the error instead it is redirecting me to the new page whose link i have given in the controller class. Please suggest me so that I can get the validation error message. PFB the code snippets.

Below is the code for the Visualforce page and the controller class

```
<apex:page standardController="Ticket_Booking__c" extensions="SaveAndNavigate">
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock Title="Book Your Ticket">
  <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Journey Information">
  <apex:inputField value="{!Ticket_Booking__c.Source__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Ticket_Booking__c.Destination__c}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Ticket_Booking__c.Date_of_Journey__c}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Passenger Information">
  <apex:inputField value="{!Ticket_Booking__c.Passenger_Information__c}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
  <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Navigate}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Class

```
public class SaveAndNavigate {
public Ticket_Booking__c ticket{get; set;}
    public String pnrNo{get; set;}
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public SaveAndNavigate(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
this.controller = controller;
}
public PageReference Navigate() {
  controller.save(); // This takes care of the details for you.
  ticket=(Ticket_Booking__c)controller.getRecord();
  pnrNo=ticket.source__c.substring(0,3).touppercase()+'-'+ticket.Destination__c.Substring(0,3).touppercase()+'-'+ticket.Date_of_journey__c.year()+ticket.Date_of_journey__c.day();
  system.debug(pnrNo);
  PageReference p= new PageReference('/apex/GeneratePNRDetails?att='+pnrNo);
 // p.setRedirect(true);
  return p;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share the logic for your validation rule and see if it is active ?

Answer (score 1):

First add `<apex:pageMessages/>` in the visualforce page.

Add try-catch block to capture exception throw it to the page.

**Update**:

I will suggest you to verify size of `List<Apexpages.Message>` just after `controller.save()` . If size is greater than 0 then return null.

```
public PageReference Navigate() {
  try
  {
    List<Apexpages.Message> msgs;
    controller.save();
    msgs = ApexPages.getMessages();
    if(msgs.size()>0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    ticket=(Ticket_Booking__c)controller.getRecord();
    pnrNo=ticket.source__c.substring(0,3).touppercase()+'-'+ticket.Destination__c.Substring(0,3).touppercase()+'-'+ticket.Date_of_journey__c.year()+ticket.Date_of_journey__c.day();
    system.debug(pnrNo);
    PageReference p= new PageReference('/apex/GeneratePNRDetails?att='+pnrNo);
    // p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;
  }catch(Exception ex)
  {
      ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, ex.getMessage());
      ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
      return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Santanu, unless the user compares the source and destination and return an error message, adding a catch block would not how the message.

Answer (score 1):

`controller.save();` will not throw any Exception in case of validation rule errors or trigger validations. It just adds the error message to the `<apex:pageMessages/>` and returns null.

So check the returned value of this method to control your flow.

```
if(controller.save() == null)
{
  return null;//end of execution. You see your errors in the page.
}
ticket=(Ticket_Booking__c)controller.getRecord();
...
return p;
```

`controller.save()` will return a valid `PageReference` instance if its a successful save, so it will not enter the if block in that case.

And of course, add `<apex:pageMessages/>` in the visualforce page.

I have faced this issue previously and learnt about this behavior in a good answer by Bob Buzzard somewhere.